# What are the various ways to iterate over map() function other than list

Tags: python

Suppose I have the some code in which I used map() function.
I know I can later print it by converting it to list just like this :

```
get_something = map(some_function, some_list)
print(list(get_something))
```

But Is there any way other than list. I mean what if I want to print not as list but line by line and don't want to use for loop every now and then?

Comment: What is wrong with using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try this:

```
print(*map(some_function, some_list),sep='\n')
```

By this `print()` will refer to map object and will print values with `\n` as a separator

Comment: why are you using " * " before map function?

Comment: As I said, You are telling ```print()``` to refer to the results produced by map as map object. Now ```print()``` will recall all those results and will do some formatting and will add ```\n``` values between the results (as given in the ```sep``` param of ```print()```) and will print it for us. If you want all results in a single line make ```sep=' '```

Comment: Jenil, I am so sorry I will disturb you once again, thanks for your explanation. I really appreciate that, but.. I have already understood that part. what I am asking is -> why are you using asterisk symbol before map function. Because usually when I have to print the map, I use list method to convert that to list. But what asterisk symbol do?

Comment: Hi, so basically you can think it of as a pointer symbol, just as we have in C and C++ whenever we are trying to point to a memory location. Example If you have `a=map(list,[1,2,3])`, and will `print(a)`, you will get something like `<map object at 0x23451460>`. This is the memory location for the object pointed by `a`. Thus by giving `*` we are referring the contents of location pointed by `a` somewhere near the location we got when we printed it and has contents that there's a map object at some loc, refering that, we use `*` this is possible due to `print()` is built on `printf()` of C

Comment: Oh.. so its all about pointer. But what data type is it holding. for example look at this. Last sentence return an error. (once more sorry :/)

def double(x):
    return x * x
lis = [2, 4, 6, 8]
get_all = map(double, lis)
print(*get_all)
print(type(get_all))
print(type(*get_all))

I can't get the data type.

Comment: Acting as a pointer, when you `print(type(get_all))` you should get `<class 'map'>`, about `print(type(*get_all))` its a iterable object with some unstructured formatting with more than one elements. So when you pass a pointed object to `type()` just like that of `get_all` , it will pass multiple args to `type()` instead of passing data only  in a "structured" form. Thus we cannot determine the type of elements in a map object unless you access them individually (using loops) or by formatting them by converting into list or so.